# .net Uri case sensitivity

Tags: .net, case-sensitive

Well lets say we have the following 2 uri's

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"http://localhost/test/");
Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"http://localhost/TEst/test123/");
Uri relativeUri = uri1.MakeRelativeUri(uri2);
```

the relativeUri holds the following value "../TEst/test123/"

i wanted the value "test123/"

So is there any way to make uri's not case sensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lower case the string before constructing the URI:

```
Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"http://localhost/TEst/test123/".ToLowerInvariant());
```

Comment: Better use ToLowerInvariant() for URIs.

Comment: Agreed. URIs are, by definition, case sensitive, so either lowercase before constructing the `Uri`, or compare them in a case insensitive manner using `String.Compare (a, b, false)`.

Comment: Well that would work, but it would require more work as im not creating the uri's on my own so i would have to convert them to strings and then back to uri's again.

Comment: @Petoj - Where do they come from then? What are you doing with the result (chances are they will be turned to strings again, so you might consider operating on the end result strings).